# Is it possible to use object position as input for texture in composite nodes?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I was trying things out in composite nodes and was wondering if it's possible to use an empty as the control for offset of a texture in composite nodes.  I couldn't find another node that could provide input and when I tried to use object mapping in the texture config itself and tie it to an empty it didn't work.  Just wondering if there is another way because that could be handy.

Comment: Is your question really about composite nodes, not material nodes?

Comment: Yes. I was doing video compositing and using a texture.

Comment: You can use drivers for this

Comment: @Crantisz Thanks that does work for me. Not as convenient but it works.  If you want to create this as an answer I can accept it.